# Group nodes in hiera by hiera-defined fact

Tags: puppet, configuration-files, hiera

I have a hierachy like this:

```
- "nodes/%{::certname}"
- (what's here is my question)
- common
```

I'd like to assign a group to my nodes in their individual configuration in hiera, like this in `nodes/hostname.yaml` :

```
---
group: alpha
```

Now, I'd like to have a file `alpha.yaml`, where I state group-specific settings.

So my question is how do I write the hierachy to ask hiera for the filename of the group definition?

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. Make sure you have the group defined in Facts.

```
- "nodes/%{::certname}"
- "%{::group}"
- common
```

So you can test with below command

```
FACTER_group=alpha puppet apply your.pp
```

For custom facts, you can go through this document: [Custom Facts Walkthrough](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.4/custom_facts.html)